# Different output using charAt and substring

Tags: java, substring, charat

Still really new to programming and am using some exercises to understand the basics. This is my assignment:

> Given a string, return a string made of the first 2 chars (if present), however include first char only if it is 'o' and include the
>   second only if it is 'z', so "ozymandias" yields "oz".
>   startOz("ozymandias") → "oz" startOz("bzoo") → "z" startOz("oxx") →
>   "o"

I already had a look at the solution a do understand it, but can't figure out why my own attempt using substring instead of 'charAt generates a different output. Why does my own code1 using substring give a different output then when I would use 'charAt? Code1 is my own attempt, code2 is the given solution. In the attachments you will find the two outputs. Thank you!

```
//code 1 own attempt
public String startOz(String str) {
String answer = "";

if ( str.length() >= 1 && str.substring( 0 ).equals("o")) {
answer =   answer + str.substring(0);
}
if ( str.length() >= 2 && str.substring( 1 ).equals("z")) {
answer =   answer + str.substring(1);
}
return answer;
}
```

[output code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7fBZ.png)

```
//code 2 the solution
public String startOz(String str) {
String answer = "";

if ( str.length() >= 1 && str.charAt( 0 ) == 'o') {
answer =   answer + str.charAt(0);
}
if ( str.length() >= 2 && str.charAt( 1 ) == 'z') {
answer =   answer + str.charAt(1);
}
return answer;
}
```

[output code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQdCc.png)

Comment: Because `substring(int beginIndex)` creates a substring from `beginIndex - string.length` and doesn´t just return a single character at `beginIndex`. You are rather looking for `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is documentation for substring(int index)

> public String substring(int beginIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the
>   end of this string.

So for first `if` you get `ozymandias` and it is not equal to `o`.
Correct would be to use:

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Documentation:

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>
> endIndex-beginIndex.

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadocs on `String#substring` - you need to add an extra parameter specifying the end of the substring, else it returns the rest of the string.